# Error while implementing Google Play Games

Tags: java, google-play-games

I am getting an error on an import statement that I am using in order to try and implement Play Games with my app.

-The import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient cannot be resolved

I have BaseGameUtils referecncing google-play-services_lib, and my project references BaseGameUtils as a library.

It's my understanding that GameClient was to have been deprecated as of February 7, 2014 but when looking at Google's sample code (e.g. ButtonClicker) it still uses this import and some of the method calls from the import.

I got the code I am using from Google's GitHub [sample app repository](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples)  for the ButtonClicker2000, some of that code has been recycled and used in the program I'm having errors with as well.

This is all the info I can think to provide, if anything more would help please let me know.

Comment: My version of BaseGameUtils does **NOT** reference GamesClient at any point (though there is still some mention of it in comments). Did you download the current version from [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples)?

Comment: I think the problem is that I have used code from GitHub and it's not updated. Do you know what exactly should be changed from the old GitHub code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with the ButtonClicker2000 example for a couple days and I was having the same problem as yours.

I think the problem in the sample code is having some lines being not updated. If you look at [that page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer), you can easily see that the updated versions of those lines are lying there. However the codes in GitHub page are not updated completely.

Because GamesClient class is removed permanently, those statements

```
GamesClient.EXTRA_PLAYERS 
GamesClient.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS 
GamesClient.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS
GamesClient.EXTRA_INVITATION
GamesClient.STATUS_OK
```

must be replaced with

```
Games.EXTRA_PLAYERS_IDS
Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS
Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS
Multiplayer.EXTRA_INVITATION
GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK
```

Also that line can be removed:

```
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient;
```

There is no need for importing GoogleApiClient because it is already imported in GameHelper.java.

After changing these lines manually and importing Multiplayer and GamesStatusCodes classes, I was successful to compile the code. I hope that solves your problem as well.

Comment: I'm going to look into implementing these changes now. Were you getting an error when trying to extend BaseGameActivity as well? I am getting an error that says "The type android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: It also may be worth noting that the import statement that imports GamesClient can be removed and, if needed, replaced with import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

Comment: In my case, there was no problem with FragmentActivity. Maybe you should check your libraries or update them.